# How to add parent folder name to all the files in a sub folder in Python

Tags: python

I would like to add a parent folder name as prefix to each file in one sub folder only. Not all subfolders.

For eg. I have a folder `C:\Users\Priya\Documents\GC0002567_20230501`

```bash
ls -lt

Images
Output_folder
Finances
Input_folder
Email
```

I would like to add the parent folder name to each file in Output_folder only.

`C:\Users\Priya\Documents\GC0002567_20230501\Output_folder`

Output_folder has 5 files:

- file1_csv
- file2_csv
- file3_docx
- file4.xlsx
- file5.log

I would like to create a script in python that would append the parent folder name as a prefix to each file in `Output_folder`

- GC0002567_20230501_file1.csv
- GC0002567_20230501_file2.csv
- GC0002567_20230501_file3.docx
- GC0002567_20230501_file4.xlsx
- GC0002567_20230501_file5.log

I have created the following code but does not work correctly.

```py
from os import walk, path, rename

for dirpath, _, files in walk(r"C:\Users\Priya\Documents\GC0002567_20230501\Output_folder"):
    for f in files:
        rename(path.join(dirpath, f), path.join(dirpath, path.split(dirpath)[-1] + '_' + f))
```

The result of the above script is:

- Output_folder_file1.csv
- Output_folder_file2.csv
- Output_folder_file3.docx
- Output_folder_file4.xlxs
- Output_folder_file5.log

Please can somebody help with the above code.
so that the final result is

- GC0002567_20230501_file1.csv
- GC0002567_20230501_file2.csv
- GC0002567_20230501_file3.docx
- GC0002567_20230501_file4.xlsx
- GC0002567_20230501_file5.log

Comment: change the `path.split(dirpath)[-1]` to `path.split(dirpath)[-2]` it should not be the `Output_folder` name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, the simplest solution is to use `splitdrive` method to remove drive from path and then split result to find directory you want to use in the new file name `tail_path.split("\\")[-2]`.

Here is example code:

```py
for dirpath, _, files in walk(r"dirpath"):
    for f in files:
        _, tail_path = path.splitdrive(dirpath)
        new_file_name = tail_path.split("\\")[-2] + '_' + f
        old_path = path.join(dirpath, f)
        new_path = path.join(dirpath, new_file_name)
        rename(old_path, new_path)
```

However, each time this script is run, this directory name will be added to the file name. I propose to implement a simple check if the file name has already been modified